# Cursor, Sqlite. How do I get the row for ID?

Tags: android

How do I get the row for ID ?
I try so it is impossible .

```
case R.id.buttonTest: {


            String[] projection = {DbTest.NAME};
            String selection = "_id = ?";
            String[] selectionArgs = { String.valueOf(1) };
             Cursor c = sqdb.query(DbTest.TABLE_NAME,projection,selection,selectionArgs ,null,null,null);
             if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DbTest.NAME));
                    textView1.setText(name);
                    }
            }

            break;
```

Comment: What is impossible? You didn't read id from table.

Comment: c.getint(0) as column number zero contain row id